A question about Wiener filter based on Linear Estimation by Kailath
In my linear estimation class based on the textbook Linear Estimation by Kailath, we went through the process of finding LLSE of $\hat{x}(t+\lambda)$ for fixed $\lambda$ given $\{y(\tau)|-\infty<\tau<t\}$ in the part where we learned about Wiener filter.
x is the unknown state. We get the measurement y and find the estimate $\hat{x}$ from it. So we want to find h(t) here I think.
We let  $$\hat{x}(t+\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}h(t-\alpha)y(\alpha)d\alpha$$.
Since $E[(x(t+\lambda)-\hat{x}(t+\lambda))y(\beta)]=0$ $\forall -\infty<\beta<t$,
distribute and substitute $\gamma=t-\beta$ and $\nu=t-\alpha$ and using WSS property,
$$ R_{xy}(t+\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}h(t)R_{yy}(\gamma-\nu)d\nu \forall 0<\gamma<\infty$$
With assumption 1, $\{H(s)\}_-=0 $, we get
$$ R_{xy}(t+\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)R_{yy}(\gamma-\nu)d\nu \forall 0<\gamma<\infty$$
and with assumption 2, $\{G(s)\}_+=0$ where $g(t) = R_{xy}(t+\lambda)-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)R_{yy}(\gamma-\nu)d\nu $, we get $-\infty<\gamma<\infty$ range so taking Laplace transform from $\gamma$ to s,
$$G(s)=e^{\lambda s}S_{xy}(s)-H(s)S_{yy}(s)$$.
Where $S=\{S\}_+ + \{S\}_-$ is additive decomposition into causal and anti-causal parts.
When you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter,
it shows you $S^+$ and $S^-$ but that's causal and anti-causal parts in canonical factorization $S=S^+S^-$, and that's mulitplicative parts, not additive decomposition. That's the notation distinction used here below too.
Then multiplying both sides by the $(S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}$ and since $\{G(s)(S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}\}_+=0$ and $\{H(s)S_{yy}(s)(S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}\}_+=H(s)S_{yy}(s)(S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}$ you get
$H(s)=\{e^{\lambda s}S_{xy}(s)(S^-_{yy}(s))^{-1}\}_+(S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}$ form. So I guess we’re trying to find h(t) using the fact that $\hat{x}(s) = \{e^{\lambda s}S_{xy}(s)(S^-_{yy}(s))^{-1}\}_+v(s)$ for the white-noise process $v(s)$, right?
But why is $y(s) = (S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}v(s)$ here?
And the next line is $S_{vv}=(S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}S_{yy}(s)(S^+_{yy}(-s))^{-T}$, which is Identity. But how was that derived from above line $y(s) = (S^+_{yy}(s))^{-1}v(s)$?
And the next line is $\hat{x}(s) = \{e^{\lambda s}S_{xv}(s)\}_+v(s)$
It's using this fact $S_{yy}(s)(S^+_{yy}(-s))^{-T}=S_{xv}(s)$. But why is that so?
And how is this form $\{e^{\lambda s}S_{xy}(s)(S^-_{yy}(s))^{-1}\}_+$ any useful? Why are we thinking about white noise?
